# NoReverseMatch in test

Tags: python, django

I get this error in one of my tests:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'plan' with arguments '()' and 
keyword arguments '{u'month': u'201604'}' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['plan(/(?P<month>[0-9]+))?$']
```

The call was

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('plan', kwargs={'month': '201604'}))
```

and the urlpattern

```
url(r'^plan(/(?P<month>[0-9]+))?$', sp_views.plan, name='plan'),
```

I tried to call `/plan/201604` without hardcoding the url. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please add a little more detail about what is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the outer argument non-capturing:

```
url(r'^plan(?:/(?P<month>[0-9]+))?$', text, name='plan'),
```

Personally, I always find this confusing, so I prefer to have two url patterns. I would include a trailing slash in the urls as well:

```
url(r'^plan/$', sp_views.plan, name='plan'),
url(r'^plan/(?P<month>[0-9]+)/$', sp_views.plan, name='plan'),
```

Comment: This non-capturing thing is really confusing. But your solution works great Thank you!

Comment: Is there a special reason, why you prefer trailing slashes?

Comment: It doesn't really matter either way, and to be honest it's unrelated to your question. Trailing slashes are common in Django, see [the tutorial for example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#writing-more-views). It prevents bugs where you submit a form to the parent url (e.g. `/parent/` instead of `/parent/child`).